# Get parameter passed in URL in Laravel view as variable directly?

Tags: php, url, laravel

Right now, if I have a parameter in a URL in one of my Laravel projects, I have to detect the route and grab the parameter:

```
Route::get('mission/{name}', 'MissionsController@show');
```

Pass the `$name` parameter as an argument to my controller:

```
class MissionsController extends BaseController {
  public function show($missionName) {
     ... 
  }
```

}

Then pass it along to the view that is returned in my controller method:

```
return View::make('missions.mission', array(
    'name' => $missionName
));
```

Before then using the `$missionName` variable in my view:

```
<p>{{ $missionName }}</p>
```

This is quite a roundabout way of doing so. Is there any way I can get the parameter from the URL directly in my view? I've tried accessing the `$_GET` superglobal, but it is empty. Surely there must be a better way of doing this.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code :

```
{{ Route::current()->getParameter('theParameterName') }}
```

**EDIT**: Above doesn't seem to be supported anymore in recent Laravel versions. You should use @lukasgeiter answer instead:

```
Route::input('name');
```

Comment: The `getParameter` method does not appear to exist.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice shortcut for  `Route::current()->getParameter()`:

```
Route::input('name');
```

Answer (score 1):

For small projects or simple examples, it may seem like this is a "roundabout" way, however this is the way it should be.  In order to create more reusable, quality code, you need to have this separation of concerns.  An over-simplified idea follows.

It is your route's job to figure out which controller needs to be called, and to make sure it is called with the correct parameters.

It is your controller's job to read the state of the application (input), communicate with the model (if needed), send the data into the view, and return the response.  There's plenty opinion on whether or not this violates the Single Responsibility Principle, but no need to go into that here.

It is the view's job to use the data passed to it to build the response.  The view shouldn't care where the data came from or how it was gotten, only that it now has it and can do what it needs.  Your `$missionName` should be able to come from a URL segment, a URL request variable, a field on a model, or any other place you can think of, but the view shouldn't know any of that.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't consider this approach. What I'm actually trying to do is resolve the Route parameter to use in a filter to check if it actually exists in my database before executing my controller, so in this case there is a requirement for it. But I do understand your argument and agree with you.