# Laravel GET request results with an additional '?' character

Tags: php, laravel, get-request

I'm getting a weird bug in Laravel while using a GET request. 
I'm performing a get request via javascript like so:

```
window.location = "messages/clone?id=" + anchorID + '&name=' + newMessageName;
```

And I'm using a `dd($request)` right away inside the controller. The desired behavior would be

```
Request->request->parameters: array:2[
'id' => 'value'
'name' => 'value'
]
```

Yet I'm having this output:

```
Request->request->parameters: array:2[
'?id' => 'value'
'name' => 'value'
]
```

You'll notice that there's an extra '?' sign right before the 'id'. I'm wondering what's the cause of this?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: Can you post the full destination url?

Comment: Pretty sure you somehow got the `?` doubled in your URL, that is about the only logical explanation I see. If it is not in the URL you see in the front end, then maybe it gets messed up by internal rewrites somehow.

Comment: The URL: http://test/templates/messages/clone?id=11&name=Aco%20Test1
The interesting thing is that it works in my local environment, it only sends the 'id' not the '?id', while on the server the data differs. I'm using the same version of Laravel.

Comment: add `/`  like this and try it  `messages/clone/?id=`

Comment: check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008011/get-parameter-passed-in-url-in-laravel-view-as-variable-directly

Comment: The '/' did not work, it produces the same result.

Comment: you can access query params by doing `request()->get('id')` dd whole `request()` if thats what you want to see.

Comment: Can you include the route definition?

Answer (score 1):

The parameters that you are dumping are arguments of `Route::get()` method. '?'`s mean is the parameter is nullable.

If you want to access get parameters you should use:

```
$request->query('id');
```

read more here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests

Comment: in dd($request) the query parameter of id also has a '?' next to it.

Comment: Could you post your Route::get method?

Comment: Route::get('clone', 'TemplatesController@clone');

Comment: But you have a parent route too.

Put this block at top level of your routes and test it.

Route::get('/test', function () {
  dd(request());
});

and then hit /test?id=5